# How to highlight Table TD when clicked?

Tags: javascript, highlight, html-table

basically I have a table grid like the one below, just a lot bigger.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And iv used CSS to make then all squares which are 60px by 60px, they wont contain any data but I want to be able to click on the individual squares so that the background color changes and if I click again it goes back to the origional background color. But I want to be able to highlight as many squares as I want.
I know it would be in JavaScript, but how would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>test 1</td>
        <td>test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test 3</td>
        <td>test 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

and script

```js
window.onload = function(){

    var all = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (var i=0;i<all.length;i++) {
        all[i].onclick = inputClickHandler;       
    }
};

function inputClickHandler(e){
    e = e||window.event;
    var tdElm = e.target||e.srcElement;
    if(tdElm.style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'){
        tdElm.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    } else {
        tdElm.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
    }
}
​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FBUmq/1/)

Comment: This works but when I click it again it doesnt remove the highlight

Comment: Solved :), when you click back.

Answer (score 2):

Well I'll post code in jQuery because I never liked how standard JS goes with selecting elements.. ;)

```
$("td").click(function() {
    if($(this).css('background-color') == 'red') { $(this).css('background-color', 'green'); }
    else { $(this).css('background-color', 'red'); }
});
```

Comment: Where did the OP stated that he wants jQuery?

Comment: Reading this it should work, but its not for some reason, and yes I changed the background color in the IF statement to suit my colors.

Comment: Well he didn't state that he doesnt want to use any library. Also i think it would be better for him if he would start to learning jQuery or other lib becouse it's very good tool for work and makes many things easier. Not to mention cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Also it does not work becouse that css('background-color') doesn't return something like 'red' / 'orange' or even #000000 but rgb(x,y,z); so that would have to be handled.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery:

```
$('td').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/CpGVK/

I like Mihai Lorga's answer as it uses pure JavaScript. However jQuery is a lot easier to develop.

Comment: Where did the OP stated that he wants jQuery?

Comment: @MihaiIorga when did the OP say he didn't want good answers with a variety of frameworks. jQuery ***IS*** JavaScript.

Comment: Then why didn't he add jQuery? I didn't downvoted you because is a good answer in case he want jQuery.

Comment: Also guys I didnt mind what code it was just so long as it works. Although iv never worked with jQuery before so not sure how to implement it, but thanks anyway guys

Comment: @MihaiIorga Why do people post questions tagged C# when they are using ASP.NET, or HTML when they are using PHP... I'm not saying my answer is the most correct answer, but it should not be hated on because of the library used.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("td").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

something like this

Comment: Where did the OP stated that he wants jQuery?

Comment: it did not, where did it state that he want plain JS?

Comment: oh jQuery is not JS, tnx dude...didnt know...rly?

Comment: there is a tag special for jQuery .. smart pants

Comment: and people use JS tag for jQuery...your argument is invalid